# Export of variable not working in child shell

Tags: linux, shell, redhat

I have a problem in my ksh script when changing the current user with the `su` command. I'm on a Redhat 6.6 Linux.

Here is an example of the part that is not working in my script:

**Connect with user1**

```
export TEST=abc

echo $TEST => abc is shown

sudo su user2 (no password set in sudoers)

echo $TEST => Variable is empty...
```

On the other machines i am using (same OS same configuration), this test is working perfectly, so i'm wondering what could cause the issue.
It seems like my "export" is not working for the child shell or is being reset.

What i've checked :

- user1 and user2 are using the same shell (bash)
- comparend results of "env" command on both users
- had it working on other machines without using `-m` or `-E` parameters on my `su` command. So this shouldn't be the cause

Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: Is the entry in /etc/sudoers different on the other machines?  That can impact how the environment is set.

Comment: hi, no it's exactly the same entry on other machines

Comment: Well, where's the code? have your read how to post a complete, verifiable and testable sample of code?